# How to get a fragment parameter from an url when response.sendRedirect is executed from a servlet ?

Tags: url, jakarta-ee, servlets, fragment, response.redirect

I have a Facebook application in Java. I use servlets and jsp's. I want to get the new url that is returned from `doPost` method `response.sendRedirect`:

```
(response.encodeRedirectURL(contextPath));
```

When response is executed , the link below is returned:

http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=AAACkWLhByJ4BADOdUCbsc390FdSayaLrfQ4VF829TFAhHj28I6LH1lW45dbU8o1ooBIuO40Q4UCBA7ZB2V9qUgKgYFuQtwIUslNHFngZDZD&expires_in=5099981

A fragment of the URL is named `access_token`. How can I get this fragment without using JavaScript or is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: did you consider the option of parsing it manually using normal java code ?

Comment: I want a code that parse it as background process than assign this value to a variable in my jsp.